# SQL: iterating through a list that contains some ranges

Tags: sql-server, list, recursion, iteration

I am trying to get information for products that have an ID that is contained in a list. The problem is that the list contains some single values and some range values:

> PX03 - PX069, PX20, PX202, PX25 - PX270, PX250 - PX2509, PX251, PX2511 -
>   PX2513

Basically what I am looking for is some way to take a list or string containing both values and ranges and the end output is a table or list that has all of the values within the ranges individually so that I can loop through them.

I have a stored procedure that loops through all the ID's in the main products table that use the 'PX' prefix, but the table has all ids (i.e. PX 1 - 9999, LX 00001 - 99999) and I only want to search through those contained in the above list. I could write it out all the id's individually but some of the ranges contain many values, which would be time consuming to go through.

My idea was to create a separate table containing this list, in which there would be three columns: an identity column, and then one column each for the beginning and end of the range. Any items that do not have a range would just have the same value for beginning and end range, i.e.:

```
----------------------------------
rownum | range_start | range_end|
----------------------------------
1        PX03         PX069
2        PX20         PX20
3        PX202        PX202
4        PX25         PX25
5        PX250        PX2509
```

and then populating a table using something like:

```
SELECT id from product_table
WHERE id BETWEEN listtable.range_start AND listtable.range_end
```

where product_table is my original table with the product id's and their information and listtable is the new table I just created. This would give me:

```
id|
---
PX03
PX030
PX031
PX032
PX033
.
.
.
PX067
PX068
PX069
PX20
PX202
PX25
PX250
PX251
```

etc.

but I am thinking I would need to iterate through the list and I am not sure how to do that. Any ideas, hints or suggestions?

**UPDATE**

After creating the table using the solution given by @asantaballa, it was as simple as using an inner join:

```
SELECT d.id
FROM product_table d
INNER JOIN @RangeTable r
ON d.id BETWEEN r.RangeFrom AND r.RangeTo
```

Comment: Are you just trying to get the rows for products where their ID is in a set of IDs?  Or is your main question about turning that list into a set of IDs?

Comment: @ryanyuyu, that is what I am trying to do, but where there is a range, I want to get all values in the range. It is not a numerical range, the field is **varchar**

Comment: Be careful when using `BETWEEN` for text ranges. For example value `PX260` is **not** between text range: `PX250-PX2509`

Comment: @Samcd Ok.  You might want to edit your question to make it more clear that you want to separate a long string with ranges into a set of IDs.  Then someone with more experience with this kind of thing might find your question more easily.

Comment: @JasonFaulkner I understand that, the values in the table are set up like that (i.e. PX25, PX250, PX2501, PX2502 ... PX2509, PX251)

Comment: Not sure about your ultimate goal, but I think you could iterate through your separate table with an EXISTS() clause.  Or if your SELECT clause is giving you the results you describe in your recent edit, you could just join to it as a derived table, or put it in a WHERE IN() clause.

Comment: String processing is not easy in SQL. Can't you create the table items in the front end system instead?

Comment: @adrianm I think putting the values into a table is the best idea. I just don't want to have to input the items within the ranges one by one, because that would take a long time, and there is the possibility I might have to do this again so I want to be able to create a procedure for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you for the part about converting the string to a table.

```
Declare @StrList Varchar(1000) = 'PX03 - PX069, PX20, PX202, PX25 - PX270, PX250 - PX2509, PX251, PX2511 - PX2513'
Declare @RangeTable Table (RangeFrom VarChar(32), RangeTo VarChar(32))
Select @StrList = Replace(@StrList,' ', '') + ','
Declare @StrListItem Varchar(32)
While CHARINDEX(',', @StrList) > 0
Begin
    Select @StrListItem = SUBSTRING(@StrList,1,CHARINDEX(',', @StrList) - 1)
    Declare
      @RangeFrom VarChar(32)
    , @RangeTo  VarChar(32)
    If CHARINDEX('-', @StrListItem) = 0
    Begin
        Select 
          @RangeFrom = @StrListItem
        , @RangeTo = @StrListItem
    End
    Else
    Begin
        Select 
          @RangeFrom = SUBSTRING(@StrListItem, 1, CHARINDEX('-', @StrListItem) - 1)
        , @RangeTo = SUBSTRING(@StrListItem, CHARINDEX('-', @StrListItem) + 1, LEN(@StrListItem) - CHARINDEX('-', @StrListItem))
    End
    Insert Into @RangeTable (RangeFrom, RangeTo) Values (@RangeFrom, @RangeTo)
    Select @StrList = SUBSTRING(@StrList, CHARINDEX(',', @StrList) + 1, LEN(@StrList) - CHARINDEX(',', @StrList))
End
Select * From @RangeTable
```

Comment: Thanks @asantaballa this is very helpful for creating the table. I am working now on creating a process, maybe by using a nested cursor, that will loop through my original ids table and find all the values that lie within the range values in the created table

Answer (score 0):

Here is your `string` and `product_table`

```
DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(100) = 'PX03 - PX069, PX20, PX202, PX25 - PX270, PX250 - PX2509, PX251, PX2511 - PX2513'

SELECT * INTO #product_table 
FROM
(
   SELECT 'PX4' PRODID
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'PX26' 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'PX75' 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'PX77'   
)TAB
```

Now create a table to hold the value

```
CREATE TABLE #listtable(ROWNUM int IDENTITY(1,1),range_start VARCHAR(100),range_end  VARCHAR(100))
```

Now insert the splitted value to the table.

```
INSERT INTO #listtable
SELECT  
ISNULL(PARSENAME(REPLACE(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'),'-','.'),2),Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')) 'range_start' ,
PARSENAME(REPLACE(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'),'-','.'),1) 'range_end' 
FROM  
(
     SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@STR, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data       
) AS A 
CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

[image]

Since Id is string, you need a function to extract numbers from Id(function created by God of SQL Server - Pinal Dave)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetNumeric
(@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @intAlpha INT
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
BEGIN
WHILE @intAlpha > 0
BEGIN
SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
END
END
RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0)
END
```

First of all keep in mind that we will not get `PX1,PX2,PX3,PX4` if you give `id BETWEEN listtable.range_start AND listtable.range_end` because those are of `varchar` type and not `numbers`. So we need to extract numbers from each `PX` and get the values between them and append `PX`.

[image]

Here is the query which filters the IDs in `product_table` which are in the range between `listtable`

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT ROWNUM,CAST(dbo.udf_GetNumeric(range_start)AS INT) NUMBERS,
   CAST(dbo.udf_GetNumeric(range_end)AS INT) RTO1 
   FROM #listtable  
   UNION ALL
   SELECT T.ROWNUM,NUMBERS+1,RTO1 
   FROM #listtable T
   JOIN CTE ON CTE.ROWNUM = T.ROWNUM
   WHERE NUMBERS < RTO1
)
SELECT PRODID IDS--,ROWNUM,NUMBERS NUMS,'PX'+CAST(NUMBERS AS VARCHAR(10)) IDS2
FROM CTE
JOIN #product_table ON PRODID='PX'+CAST(NUMBERS AS VARCHAR(10))
ORDER BY NUMBERS
option (MaxRecursion 0)
```

- **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/701cb/1)**

Comment: In the example, PX05 is not in list but is between PX03 and PX069 where ROWNUM is 1. When PX05 is in product_table, do you want to show PX05  since PX05 is between  PX03 and PX069(ROWNUM = 1) ? @Sam cd

Comment: I would like all values (from a different table) that are between the range_start and range_end columns to be included. I don't think there is any need for the GetNumeric function, as the values that I am ordering are in **varchar**